# how can i divide grouped masked id by a value that is in another df (the df contains a value for each masked id )

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,'A', 4], [1,'B', 2], [2,'C', 5], [2,'A', 5], [3,'B', 2]],
                  columns=['maskedid ', 'test  ', 'value'])

    maskedid test  value
     1        A      4
     1        B      2
     2        C      5
     2        A      5
     3        B      2
```

I want to group by 'maskedid' and 'test' and run .describe () i order to find the count and divide the count output by a value from another dataframe. #each masked id has its own value .

df with the below values

```
maskedid value 
 1        5      
 2        6      
 3        7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that you want to generate the `.describe()` info and divide the data generated by the other dataframe (`df2`).  You can acheive it this way:

```
df.groupby(['maskedid', 'test']).describe()


              value                                  
              count mean std  min  25%  50%  75%  max
maskedid test                                        
1        A      1.0  4.0 NaN  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0
         B      1.0  2.0 NaN  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
2        A      1.0  5.0 NaN  5.0  5.0  5.0  5.0  5.0
         C      1.0  5.0 NaN  5.0  5.0  5.0  5.0  5.0
3        B      1.0  2.0 NaN  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
```

Then, divide by `df2` matching `maskedid` by:

```
df.groupby(['maskedid', 'test']).describe().div(df2.set_index('maskedid')['value'], axis=0, level=0)
```

**Result:**

```
                  value                                                                
                  count      mean std       min       25%       50%       75%       max
maskedid test                                                                          
1        A     0.200000  0.800000 NaN  0.800000  0.800000  0.800000  0.800000  0.800000
         B     0.200000  0.400000 NaN  0.400000  0.400000  0.400000  0.400000  0.400000
2        A     0.166667  0.833333 NaN  0.833333  0.833333  0.833333  0.833333  0.833333
         C     0.166667  0.833333 NaN  0.833333  0.833333  0.833333  0.833333  0.833333
3        B     0.142857  0.285714 NaN  0.285714  0.285714  0.285714  0.285714  0.285714
```

---

**Input Used**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,'A', 4], [1,'B', 2], [2,'C', 5], [2,'A', 5], [3,'B', 2]],
                  columns=['maskedid', 'test', 'value'])

   maskedid test  value
0         1    A      4
1         1    B      2
2         2    C      5
3         2    A      5
4         3    B      2


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'maskedid': [1, 2, 3], 'value': [5, 6, 7]})

   maskedid  value
0         1      5
1         2      6
2         3      7
```

Comment: yes exactly, i want to divide the count of how many times each test has occurred for each user by the value of its corresponding masked id from df2. 
i have noticed that u have created a dictionary in df2 , what can i do if am going to import df2 from a csv file ?

Comment: @AhmadOkasha  I didn't create any dictionary on df2.  Just set index on the column `maskedid` and get its value for division.  You can say the effect is a bit like a dictionary by setting index for lookup.  For importing from a csv file, you can refer to the official document of pd.read_csv [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: @AhmadOkasha  I guess what you just mentioned about the dictionary would be on my example of creating `df2` by `pd.DataFrame`, right ?   That is a general syntax we can specify column names and the corresponding values by lists.   You can refer to the official doc of pd.DataFrame [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) to get more examples of using dictionary to define a dataframe.

Comment: yes i was referring to your df2. so if i understood right , it should work fine when i import my df2 from a csv without changing it to look as your df2

Comment: @AhmadOkasha  Yes, that's right.  You can create df2 in any way, so long as the final dataframe layout is the same the solution is the same.